# OpenCover with Xunit Visited Classes 0 of 1

Tags: xunit.net, opencover

Am trying to integrated Xunit.net framework with opencover, When I try to get the code coverage for my dll, Opencover doesn't pick my dll, whereas Xunit its executing its summary and printing its result.

`C:\CodeProject\packages\OpenCover.4.6.166\tools\OpenCover.Console.exe -output:"C:\CodeProject\SampleXunit.Test\coverage.xml" -target:"C:\CodeProject\packages\xunit.runner.console.2.1.0\tools\xunit.console.exe" -targetargs:"""C:\CodeProject\SampleXunit.Test\bin\Debug\SampleXunit.Test.dll" """C:\CodeProject\SampleXunit.Test\bin\Debug\Sample.dll" /noshadow" -register:user -filter:+[*]*
C:\CodeProject\packages\ReportGenerator.1.9.1.0\reportgenerator C:\CodeProject\SampleXunit.Test\coverage.xml C:\CodeProject\SampleXunit.Test\coverage
start C:\CodeProject\SampleXunit.Test\coverage\index.htm`

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Fixed it... After investigating the Coverage.xml, dependency dll's was not loaded properly. After specifying the `-targetdir:` attribute, it worked for me.

Comment: Also Appveyor might needs `-targetdir:` attribute. Nice work!

Comment: What value did you set to `-targetdir:` attribute? Also, may you edit your answer with the correct full comand so that we can see exactly how you solved it? Thanks.